# Undefined control sequence \SetKwProg

Tags: texlive, algorithm2e

The minimal (not) working example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[algo2e,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm2e}[h]
  \SetKwProg{myproc}{Procedure}{}{}    
  \myproc{foo()}{
   $\ldots$
  }   
 \end{algorithm2e} 
\end{document}
```

This example works on Windows with latest version of portable Miktex. However, it doesn't work on Linux (I try Ubuntu and Debian) with texlive installed. Both Linux system is updated. The error I got on Linux is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6   \SetKwProg
            {myproc}{Procedure}{}{}
```

Note, that with texlive I successfully Latex many algorithms, the only command which is not working is `\SetKwProg`. Any suggestion how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Include `\listfiles` as part of your document preamble and check your `.log` for the version number of [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). It should report the same as what's on CTAN: 5.0. If not, then you don't have the most up-to-date version, so read [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: Package `algorithm2e' Release 3.9 -- october 04 2005. It is probably old.I hope that system will offer updates when they exist. I am going to read manual for updating.

Comment: You can [download `algorithm2e` from CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and place it your local TEXMF folder or overwrite the existing version in your tree. Remember to refresh the filename database afterwards (`mktexlsr`).

Comment: For more on this, see [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://goo.gl/ByVnz), since you'll be using "your own" version of `algorithm2e`.

Comment: I am trying to put this package in my local TEXMF folder, but I cannot find it. /usr/local/texlive does not exist on my system as well as ~/texmf. Is there some command to find my local tex folder?

Comment: If using linux: `which pdflatex`.

Comment: `which pdflatex` returns `/usr/bin/pdflatex`, but I am not sure that this is proper place to put algorithm package.

Comment: I solve it. Create directories `~/texmf/tex/latex/` and put the algorithm2e folder in it, run `mktexlsr` and now it's working. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you have an older version of the `algorithm2e` package. The command `\SetKwProg` is supported only by the latest version 5.0.

TeX Live on Debian and Ubuntu is known to be not updated.

The thread [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/27635) might help you on what to do to get an updated version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what should I do to resolve this? There is no update for texlive on my system and algorithm2e is part of `texlive-science` package, which is up to date. Is there some equivalent command which works on previous versions?

Comment: @Petar: besides Werner's comment up, you have to consider that if you installed TeX Liva via apt-get, you probably do not have a recent distribution as karlkoeller pointed. The link he provided might help you in installing an updated TeX Live, which is TeX Live 2013 out from few days.